# TestCafe with sauce lab plugins- Error : Cannot establish one or more browser connections

Tags: node.js, npm, testcafe, browser-automation, saucelabs

When run a script in testcafe with Sauce Labs. Testcafe is able to open browser but it is not connecting. The following error is getting frequently when the script is running more than one AWS instances and also in my local

Error: Cannot establish one or more browser connections.
1 of 4 browser connections have not been established:

- saucelabs:Chrome@latest:Windows 10

Hints:

- The host machine may not be powerful enough to handle the specified concurrency factor (4). Try to decrease the concurrency factor or allocate more computing resources to the host machine.
- Increase the value of the "browserInitTimeout" option if it is too low (currently: 1 minute for all browsers). This option determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.
- The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.

I tried to decrease the thread count from 5 to 1 but no luck and also I increased the regression image size to 7GB in AWS CICD build and tried all hints specified above

Appreciate your help if anyone can provide solution.

Software versions:

node -v v18.14.0

npm -v 9.4.1

"testcafe-browser-provider-saucelabs": "^1.9.0"

testcafe -v 1.17.1

Comment: The cause of the issue is not clear. If you want the TestCafe team to research the issue, please create a separate thread in the official TestCafe repository using the following link: [create a bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml).

Please also refer to the following help topic before submitting the issue: [How to create a minimal working example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue).